# Maximum length for url in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, url, browser

I have seen this popular question:

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

But since I couldn't find a reference to Google Chrome directly (and since most answers were given a few years ago) I was wondering what is the current limitation of URL length for the Google Chrome browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe it's stayed the same:

> I could not find any limits on Chrome and Safari. Both are based on WebKit and it seems to have similar limits as Firefox has.
>
> Firefox stops displaying after 64k characters, but can serve more than
> 100k characters.

you can read more about it [in this article.](http://wiert.me/2010/04/20/maximum-url-lengths/)

Generally speaking there is no "limit" to a URL's length, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733386/2091793) states that you should keep your URL's under 2048 chars regardless to make sure it works in every client and server.

[**More information about all browsers here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/2091793)

Comment: @SteveCampbell better?

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question, the quote on the site is about Firefox not Chrome, and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @callum A quote from the site: "I could not find any limits on Chrome and Safari. Both are based on WebKit and it seems to have similar limits as FireFox has."

Comment: Right, but in your answer you quoted a line about Firefox

Comment: ... because it is the same as Chrome

Comment: firefox is branched from mozilla, while chrome and safari are branched from webkit.  but they are definitely more similar to each other than I.E. so @chriz is pretty spot on.  I think we can usually assume I.E. will always be lagging in terms of "luxury" features.

Answer (score 22):

The current limit in Chrome is 2MB. This issue is discussed here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227

You'll find resources there such as a workaround when you need to overcome the issue for things such as displaying an image with a "toDataUrl" source.

Comment: 2MB is equivalent to 2,097,152 characters, which is quite different to the length on the accepted answers on the other thread (2,000 characters).

Comment: That threat says 2MB may be the limit with respect to serializing data, which appears to be a reference to the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (as in a uniform resource _identifier_) rather than an actual HTTP(S) URL (as in a uniform resource _location_, a subset of URIs). The [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/519360 "What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?") says that as of January 2021, Chrome's limit is 32779 in the location bar and >64k in document.location or an anchor tag.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that handling a URL might be implementation-dependent, the `HTTP/1.1` specifications states in the *`RFC2616`* that :

> RFC 2616 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol — HTTP/1.1) states in section
>   3.2.1 that there is no limit to the length of an URI (URI is the official term for what most people call a URL).

I do not know how many maximum characters would be, at maximum, be accepted by Google Chrome, and don't even know if there currently exists such a limit. Perhaps would it be specified in an obscure define in the [Chromium GIT repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/) or even specified by the maximum value of a text input in the `Win32 API` on windows for example.

However there is a limit on most web servers regarding URL lengths. They will probably in most cases throw a `413 Entity Too Large` in response.

Answer (score -2):

In theory it should be unlimited, However in practise, most of the Http Clients or Browsers are limited to 2083 characters of Url Length.