# How to send string(say: public_Key) having special characters in URL?

Tags: php, html, query-string, url-parameters

When I said simple string It works fine, but when I send my public_key string in the same way, It shows error.

I have tried the `urlencode()` method.

```
<iframe src="http://local.abc.com/formulaList?id=<?php echo $public_key; ?>"  >
```

Answer (score 2):

`base64()` doesn't work because its output can contain slashes (and anyway, most public key strings are already base64 encoded)

`htmlspecialchars()` escapes HTML special chars as its name implies which has nothing to do with urls (for example, `é` will be converted to `&eacute;`)

`urlencode()` is the right function to use but keep in mind an URL shouldn't be too long as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733386/1762556)

What problem did you encounter when using `urlencode()` ?

Answer (score -2):

I write something this might work.

```
$url =  htmlspecialchars("wdsd@ccddsd*");
header("Location: https://www.google.com?key={$url}");
```

this will work for you!

Comment: htmlspecialchars is for escaping HTML ... special chars such as "à", "é", "è", "~", "ô", etc...

Comment: But it working when Header() Load it. You can copy and check results on your side.