# Polling docusign envelope status limit

Tags: docusignapi

How many DocuSign envelope statuses can I get at a time by calling the [API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus)

> PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=[list_of_ids]

I have a bulk number of envelope Ids and it is increasing day by day. What I am going to do is, I am going to pull all the envelope statuses (except the voided and completed envelopes) in a scheduler manner.

I have not found anything or I have missed in the documentation. Is there a limitation in docusign with the number or request size ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458445/what-is-a-safe-maximum-length-a-segment-in-a-url-path-should-be/33733386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two limits: the max length of a URL including its query parameters, and the max envelope ids for the call.

Avoiding the URL length limit: As [documented](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus), you can set the query parameter to a special value: `envelope_ids=request_body`. In this case, the method uses the envelope IDs in the request body.

From the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus):

> `envelope_ids` query parameter -- The envelope IDs to include in the results.
>
> The value of this property can be:
>
> A comma-separated list of envelope IDs. [or]
>   The special value `request_body`. In this case, the method uses the envelope IDs in the request body.

I don't know what the second limit is.

As an alternative, consider setting up a webhook. You can receive the webhook notifications of completed envelopes from behind the firewall (without changing the firewall) by using an intermediate queuing system.

Example code for AWS, Azure, and Google Cloud is available for C#, Java, PHP, Python, and Node.js. See the `Connect-*` repositories in github.com/docusign

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm. I found nothing regarding `envelope_ids=request_body` in the docusign api documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the check. I've added the docs excerpt. I agree that it is hard to find. -- Also, be sure to look at the default (v2.1) documentation. The v2 docs are older.