# Length limit for parameter in TFS API?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-devops-rest-api

I try to get the last builds of some build definitions in my TFS (Team Foundation Server) with:

```
project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=1000,1001&queryOrder=queueTimeDescending&minTime=2020-05-03T00:00:00
```

This works until the string for "definitions" reach a limit of 440 definitions or 1984 characters.
Then I get a 404-Error on the request.

Is there such an (undocumented) limit in the number of definitions or length for the parameter string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clearly state how long url can be, but it looks that you reached the limit. However according to this [What is a safe maximum length a segment in a URL path should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458445/what-is-a-safe-maximum-length-a-segment-in-a-url-path-should-be/33733386) it is good practice to do not extend 2000 characters. I see that you count almost 2K, so this maybe is your case.

You can also check this [topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/336135/vststfs-extension-development-url-limit-for-get-re.html) on developer community. There were discussion about this with conclusion:

> At present, you can only reduce the length of URL.